# Chrome Extension message not sending response (undefined)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

**For future reference:** I solved this by switching the onMessage/sendMessage to the background script and the content script, respectively. I'm not sure why this worked, but it did.

I've been trying to debug this for the past three hours--I'm building a chrome extension and I've been getting "undefined" as the response to a message I send. I'm trying to get the text of the tab the user is on and use it to do some analysis.

Content Script:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
        if (request.method == "collectText") {
            sendResponse({data: document.body.innerText, method: "collectText"});
        }
        return true;
    }
);
```

Popup Script:

```
chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
  chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {method: "collectText"}, function(response) {
      if (response) {
        txt = response.data;
        console.log("response arrived");
        console.log(txt);
      } else {
        console.log("No response.");
      }
  });
});
```

The console.logs are currently there so that I know if the data is coming back (it's not--"No response" is logged every time the scripts run, and `txt` ends up undefined). I'm not sure why this isn't working (& I've tried many variations on the same scripts to no avail). I'm not getting any errors in the console of either the extension or the page I'm on. Should I be using a background script instead of writing everything inside popup.js?

Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure you're using all of the required parameters for [`chrome.tabs.sendMessage()`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-sendMessage)?

Comment: I don't think the options are relevant here, so I think I am.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future reference: I solved this by switching the onMessage/sendMessage to the background script and the content script, respectively. I'm not sure why this worked, but it did.

Comment: I wish I understood what you mean by this. I have the same problem for the past two days and am losing the will to live...

Answer (score 17):

This type of errors can happen if you return an answer asynchronously.
(Although that could not happen on the example you have given)

```js
// sender
runtime.sendMessage(msg, response => {
  if (!response)
    console.error("This was a fiasco :", runtime.lastError.message);
});

// receiver
runtime.onMessage.addListener(async (request, sender, sendResponse) => {
  var response = await answer_something(request);
  sendResponse(response);
});

// same problem for this receiver
runtime.onMessage.addListener((request, sender, sendResponse) => {
  promise_something(request).then(response => {
    sendResponse(response);
  });
});
```

In such case you would see the following error : `Unchecked runtime.lastError: The message port closed before a response was received`

To fix it, you must return `true` from an asynchronous `onMessage` listener. Note that returning a promise will NOT work on chrome ([docs for chrome](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#event-onMessage), [docs for firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/runtime/onMessage)).

Comment: Wow, returning true worked like magic for my async function. Thanks!

Comment: Ok great, that works if we use Promise.then() and return true in the onMessage, and also we must use Promise.then() in sendMessage otherwise an await in sendMessage doesn't work either

Answer (score 14):

For me the problem was that the listener function was `async`. I just wanted to use `await` but this causes the listener to return a `Promise` instead of `true`. You need to wrap your handler in an async function.

Before (incorrect):

```js
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(async function (request: any, sender, sendResponse) {
  debug('Got message', request);
  if (request.type === 'updateUser') {
    const responseUser = await getUser();
    user = responseUser;
    await chrome.storage.local.set({ user });
    sendResponse({ user });
  }

  return true;
})
```

After:

```
const handleUpdateUser = async (sendResponse: (response: any) => void) => {
  const responseUser = await getUser();
  user = responseUser;
  await chrome.storage.local.set({ user });
  sendResponse({ user });
};

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (request: any, sender, sendResponse) {
  debug('Got message', request);

  if (request.type === 'updateUser') {
    handleUpdateUser(sendResponse);
  }
  
  return true;
})
```

Comment: That was exactly my problem. Nice catch.

Comment: Perfect! Worked for me

Answer (score 3):

You probably get an error, because of the code + [comment](https://github.com/JasperDragon/Chromium/blob/028bdfc4042c3ff070f81fc8e2630b919f2f09d5/extensions/renderer/resources/messaging.js#L343):

```
// According to the documentation of chrome.runtime.sendMessage, the
// callback is invoked without any arguments when an error occurs
```

You need to check an [`lastError`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#property-lastError) 
property to get info about an error and fix it.

Hope, that will help.

Comment: I'm not getting any `lastError` errors on the tab or the popup script.

Comment: Hm, can you try to run your popup script as background page script and check result?

Comment: Putting the script in background.js doesn't work either. I put the same code with a `var txt = "hi";` at the top, and when I call txt from popup.js, I get "hi" and not the text the extension should be gathering from the current tab.

Comment: I've just check your example with run on the background page - and it works for me. What I did - I've just add `setTimeout` to the `chrome.tabs.query` and make an active tab not `devtools`.
Maybe your problem is that at the moment of execution active tab is `devtools` or `chrome://extensions`? With this tabs it will work incorrect.

Comment: Thanks for this tip ... I had to click "inspect views" to see the error generated by the background script.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this problem is to move the content of the scripts so that the listener is in the background script, and the message is sent from the content script.

Popup communicating with content script won't achieve what you want.

**Visually:**

Before, not working:

Popup script ----(message)---> content script

After, working:

Content script ----(message)---> background script

I see a comment on OP's own answer saying "I wish I knew what you meant" with 2 upvotes! So I post my own answer, to both visually represent the solution to OP's problem, and to answer commentator's and the 2 up-voters question in one answer. How is this an answer you vote to delete 'as it doesn't answer the question'? I have tested this on my end and it works.